# mySQL - Count Distinct Over Multiple Columns, as One

Tags: mysql, count, distinct-values

I have a mySQL DB in which two columns may refer to the same Identifier. One column is PartyA and the other is PartyB (as in counter-parties to an exchange, or nodes in a graph).

Curious if there is an easy mySQL query to find the unique count of Party Identifies?

Currently I pull PartyA, then PartyB, row-bind the two, then count distinct.

---

E.g.:

[image: example]

Clearly the distinct count of PartyA and PartyB is 9, even through neither PartyA nor PartyB have a distinct count of 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM (
   SELECT PartyA FROM theTable 
   UNION 
   SELECT PartyB FROM theTable
) AS pQ;
```